# Sending File via Bluetooth using Intent Action SEND does not working in android 4.2.2?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bluetooth

I have used Intent-SEND to share the files via bluetooth.I have add my code here.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);       
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.bluetooth",
            "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity"));

    intent.setType("text/plain");

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/Sample.txt");
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    startActivity(intent);
```

This code is not working in android version 4.2.2. While running this code in android verison 4.2.2 , getting Exception:

```
        android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity   class {com.android.bluetooth/com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

But this code working fine in below android 4.2.X. why this code is not working in android 4.2.2?.

Comment: http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2010/11/android-bluetooth-rfcomm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share the file by bluetooth like this:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(picURI);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Sample.txt");

sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share file"));
```

Comment: hi Ankit , its working fine. thanks a lot. we can't directly send files via bluetooth without choosing bluetooth?. We need to choose buletooth for every time know.

Comment: Remove "Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share file") " from start activity and directly call sharingIntent.

Comment: its same as above code. its getting activity not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the packageName instead of the component

```
intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
```

Comment: hi lon Aalbers , i have tested using intent.setPackage("") and also bluetoothshare. but its also not working in higher versions (android 4.2.x).