# Unable to find explicit activity class (Bluetooth)

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

Good Morning

I am trying to send excel file to a PC via Bluetooth, but I am getting the following error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.bluetooth/com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

My code for handling sending operation is:

```
private void ShareReportToPc() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CoiAppFiles/COI-Report.xls");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("application/excel");
        intent.setClassName("com.android.bluetooth", "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

And the code of Manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="iq.nazaha.wissam.CoiApp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginPage"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainPage"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AddNewItemPage"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".EditItemPage"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ReportsPage"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutPage"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I searched many answers, some of them suggests to include the name of the activity in the AndroidManifest which I already did, others suggests to clean the project but it didn't solve the problem. I believe its very silly mistake but I became blind. Any help please?

Comment: Where is the activity declared in the manifest?

Comment: @sanketpahuja the activity is ReportsPage.

Comment: have you checked if the activity exists in the android.bluetooth package?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean, how I can check that?

Comment: Simply type android.bluetooth anywhere and you will get a list of suggestions. Select any one and the control/command+click on it. The file will open, then click on the package and you can view the entire android.bluetooth package in the package explorer

Comment: @sanketpahuja the class "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity" is exist in the package "com.android.bluetooth".

Comment: have you tried including tag of BluetoothOppLauncherActivity in your manifest?

Comment: I am beginner to android programming and this is my first project. However, I read right now that tags is not allowed in the Manifest, How to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955691/sending-file-via-bluetooth-using-intent-action-send-does-not-working-in-android

Comment: Well, changing 'Intent.setClassName("com.android.bluetooth", "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity");' to 'Intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");' and using chooser solved the problem. Thank you @sanketpahuja

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't vote until earning 15 reputation at least. However, post your comment as answer and I will accept it :) thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest replacing `intent.setClassName("com.android.bluetooth", "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity");` with `intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");`